# Errors with declaring/defining and vectors

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I'm working on some code and I've come across a few errors to do with defining/declaring and expecting a type specifier where my class name is?

I was wondering if anyone can simply explain to me where I've gone wrong and how to resolve these issues?

I've commented out the errors on each lines, Boot and Shoe and Footwear are classes in a header file `Footwear.h`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "typedefs.h"
#include "Footwear.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    vector<Footwear*> collection;       // vector and Footwear are undefined 

    Footwear* f;                        //f undefined

    f = new Boot("Timbaland",10);       //expected a type specifier

        collection.push_back(f);        //collection undefined

    f = new Shoe("Brogue",5);           //expected a type specifier

    collection.push_back(f);                        

    for (i = 0; i < collection.size(); i++)     //i undefined
    collection[i]>toString();           //toString undefined

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: vector is in the namespace std, so if you write `std::vector` that will solve it. As for the rest of them, please provide your header file so that we can see how you defined the classes

Comment: also: "i undefined" you have to write `for( type i = 0 ; ... ; ... )` or declare it beforehand (replace `type` by `int` or the type you want); `collection[i]>toString();` what does `>` mean here?

Comment: @Caninonos betting `>` is a typo of `->`. Danny, on the off chance you're coming in from java and haven't already been warned, there is no toString() method for objects by default in C++. C++ has no `class object` or similar from which all classes inherit. You'll have to define it yourself.

Comment: reiterating @MaksimSolovjov 's request for Footwear.h. `std::vector` will only solve part of the problem if the Footwear class can't be found.

Answer (score 1):

Use: `std::vector`

That may clear all the warnings. You've included  but you still need to prefix the `std` namespace.

In your for loop, you must declare `for(int i = 0....)` you may want to use `unsigned int` since `collection.size()` should never be `< 0`.

Comment: Please don't advise `using namespace std; `!

Comment: Removed my suggestion :)